# how to SSH into a computer that's in a different WLAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh

My current network set up is 
Internet -> ISP wifi router (broadcasting) ----(LAN output to)---> my own wifi router (broadcasting)

pc1 connects wifi to ISP wireless router, my pc2 connects wifi to my own wifi router. Hence they are not in the same LAN. I want to SSH from pc2 to pc1. How do I set this up?

If this is impossible, I have an alternative set up. My own wifi router has dual band, and my pc2 is currently using the higher band (and can only use the higher band), my pc1 can use the lower band. Now that if they are connected to the same router, can this be done?

Comment: Seem like complicated, but how about using VPN server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router is a device which separate VLAN, unless you have access to modify the config ISP wifi router (Since this is maintained by ISP so usually you don't have access to it), this can't be done.

EDIT:
Just reviewed your network environment and this can be done, as my understanding, you are currenting having the following networking configuration:

```
ISP router:
WAN IP: 123.123.123.123 (Just a public IP for example)
LAN and WIFI IP: 10.0.0.1~10.0.0.254

Your own router:
WAN IP: 10.0.0.2 (Dynamic IP obtained from the ISP router DHCP)
LAN and WIFI IP: 192.168.1.1~192.168.1.254
```

If your ISP router is not separating WLAN & LAN client, you can disable DHCP form your own wifi router and plug it to the LAN port, this will make your own wifi router as a switch under ISP router. So the network will become:

```
ISP router:
WAN IP: 123.123.123.123
LAN and WIFI IP: 10.0.0.1~10.0.0.254

Your own router:
WAN IP: N/A (as I mentioned, now it works as a switch so dont have WAN IP)
LAN and WIFI IP: 10.0.0.1~10.0.0.254 (IP pool assigned by ISP router DHCP pool)
```

Now you are on the same subnet and should have no problem to SSH now.

Example screen of some brand of router of AP Isolation function, just remember to disable it on your ISP and your own router

[image]

Comment: Not true at all, you only need to change your router to either forward ports or share the same subnet. The "WAN" side of the personal router is on the same subnet as OP's PC1

Comment: Thanks for advise, just misread situation, now this can be done, take some time to edit the solution :)

Comment: No problem, you answer is more concise than what I started writing. The hard part is making sure that Router2 is not creating a VLAN but just acting as a switch, this may be a configuration option, but it will probably require that OP plugs the ISP router into the "LAN" switch of router2 and not the "WAN" port

Answer (score 0):

Check your router settings for "bridged mode" or a way to disable DHCP.  This will basically turn it into a switch and combine the two networks into one.